# Join data from two data frame

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have two data frame that I want to join from `df2` to `df` by using values of `df2` rows. Something as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Definition': ['Loan', 'Deposit'], 
                   '20231015': [28, 17],
                   '20231016': [5, 6],
                   '20231017': [10, 13],
                   'Notes':['','']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'BR_CD': ['Hanoi', 'Hochiminh'], 
                   'CUS_NM': ['A', 'B'],
                   'AMT': ['2', '3']})
df2['Conclusion'] = "[" + df2['BR_CD'] + "]" + ' ' + df2['CUS_NM'] + ' ' + df2['AMT'] 
x = "[" + df2['BR_CD'] + "]" + ' ' + df2['CUS_NM'] + ' ' + df2['AMT']
for i in x:
    df['Notes'].iloc[1] = i
df
```

With this code, `df['Notes'` just take last value of i:

[image]

But my goal is show show all values from `df2['Conclusion]`:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Definition': ['Loan', 'Deposit'], 
                   '20231015': [28, 17],
                   '20231016': [5, 6],
                   '20231017': [10, 13],
                   'Notes':['','[Hanoi] A 2;[Hochiminh] B 3']})
df3
```

[image]

If possible I want to down the line for each conclusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not using directly:

```
df['Notes'].iloc[1] = ';'.join(x)
```

Or, better:

```
df.iloc[1, df.columns.get_loc('Notes')] = ';'.join(x)
```

Output:

```
  Definition  20231015  20231016  20231017                        Notes
0       Loan        28         5        10                             
1    Deposit        17         6        13  [Hanoi] A 2;[Hochiminh] B 3
```

Comment: My bad, I was thinking in a complicated way. Is there any way to make the conclusion down the line? (Instead of `;`, it will be `Enter`). Thank you.

Comment: Yes, use `'\n'.join` instead of `';'.join`